# file transfer with BLE

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, driver, file-transfer

I use a X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1 with a NUCLEO-L476RG .

I want to transfer a file (a driver) with the BLE, is it possible?

Or does the X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1 allow the use of bluetooth BR / EDR to transmit files with the OPP profile?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, transferring files over BLE is possible. Keep in mind that BLE only allows small data packages to be sent as one message and you probably need to split your file yourself. The maximum throughput of BLE is also less then with Bluetooth Classic since it is designed for 'Low Energy' usage

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to create a custom service or are there services available? I saw that there is the Object Transfer Service, but in the documentation it is written that the L2CAP LE Credit Based Flow Control Mode shall be supported. I don't know if it is supported by the  X-NUCLEO-BNRG2A1

Comment: You could use the existing Object Transfer Service and use L2CAP, but I don't know what your device supports. There should be no restrictions to use a service, but you might not have a L2CAP API. You could also use your own custom characteristic which would prevent other apps to send files without knowing your exact protocol. It all depends on your usecase